# Open email links in Start Chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8, modern-ui

I would like to know if I can force Windows 8 to use the Modern UI version of Chrome when opening links, rather than the desktop version?

Answer (score 1):

Unlike IE 10, there is only one "version" of Google Chrome on Windows 8, which can be run in either Desktop or Modern UI mode.

So - if you always want links to open Google Chrome in Modern UI mode, start Chrome, then when it's running select "Relaunch Chrome in Windows 8 mode" from the menu (see below).

From then on, Chrome will run in Windows 8 Modern UI mode, and links will automatically go there.

To revert back, repeat the process, which will now say "Relaunch Chrome on the Desktop"

[image]